# Android forgets ringtone settings after USB connected as mass storage

Tags: ringtone, usb-mass-storage

Every time I turn on USB as mass storage device, my phone forgets its ringtone.

This is somewhat reasonable, because the OS doesn't have access to these file while the flash belongs to another computer. But I expect that the settings to revert or be kept after it's disconnected.

Is there a way to keep it remember ringtone settings?

Current settings (but it happened on other models as well):

- ZTE
- CM12

Comment: Since it's on CM12 (rooted, naturally), could you just move your desired ringtone to `/system/media/audio/ringtones`?

Comment: thanks. it's important to remember to set permissions at least 444 (my copy command didn't set the last 4, and the phone was not able to play these files)
please write it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your desired ringtone to `/system/media/audio/ringtones` and set proper permissions (refer to other files in the folder).